# Как инициализировать mustache, чтобы он подгружал шаблоны аяксом ?

Tags: ajax, mustache, javascript

Недавно начал пользоваться шаблонизатором mustache, полагая что смогу использовать его как на сервере, так и на клиенте в ajax-сайтах, где и контент и шаблоны должны цепляться динамически. В php выполняю init, указывая в параметрах loader и partials_loader пути к папкам с шаблонами. Таким образом, компиляция данных выполняется в одну строку типа

```
<?php $mustache->loadTemplate($tmplname)->render($context);
```

Несколько раз перечитал мануляр по JS библиотеке, но ни параметра папки, ни подобного метода не нашёл. Как бы его туда пихнуть, так чтобы всё работало как в примере с пыхом ?

Comment: у вас jQuery используется ? можно с ней пример накатать.
[вот тут описано как](http://www.jonnyreeves.co.uk/2012/using-external-templates-with-mustache-js-and-jquery/)

Comment: папка, путь, path, расположение... - можно назвать как угодно.

чую, готовых решений нет, никто не собирается помочь моей лени, и самому придётся перечитать весь исходник и переписать все под себя самому

дописать в объект mustache нужные параметры и реакцию на них соответствующих функций с асинхронной загрузкой